# Question on a group of order $24$

Tags: abstract-algebra

(Let $n_p$ denote the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups)

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $24$ such that $n_2 >1$. Let $K$ be the intersection of all normalizers of Sylow $3$-subgroups of $G$. Assume that $|K|=2$. Then, why does every Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ contain $K$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. Show that $K\unlhd G$.
2. If $P$ and $K$ are $2$-subgroups of $G$ and $K\unlhd G$ show that $PK=\{pk\mid p\in P, k\in K\}$ is also a $2$-subgroup of $G$.
3. What does the second bullet imply, when $P$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

The interesection of all those normalizers is a normal subgroup of the group, and *any* normal $\;p\,-$ subgroup is always contained in **all** Sylow $\;p\,-$ subgroups of that group (this follows from Sylow's theorems). Fill in details.

Comment: I asked for the case $p\neq q$.